MAUI search handler disappears when navigating between flyout item
i have a custom search handler which is used inside the content page xaml(this is the main page which is the first flyout item in the shell).I also have multiple flyout items.

From my first flyout item i am navigating to other sub pages
From the subpage i am navigating to the flyout item
From this flyout item i am navigating to the first flyout item

The search handler in the first flyout item disappeared while trying above.
I tried to clear the navigation stack while navigating from one flyout item to other.
I also verified all the registering process
when navigating back to the main flyout item i need to show the search handler
i have added search handler like below in one of the flyout content page.
<Shell.SearchHandler
    Placeholder="Enter search term"
    ShowsResults="true">
    <handlers:CustomSearchHandler x:Name="CustomSearchHandler " BindingContext="{Binding Source={x:Reference Name=MainPageViewModel}}"
        Placeholder="{Binding [SearchCustomCode], Source={x:Static util:Translator.Instance}}">
        <handlers:CustomSearchHandler.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:CustomModel">
                <Label Margin="2,4" Text="{Binding Name}"></Label>
            </DataTemplate>
        </handlers:CustomSearchHandler .ItemTemplate>
    </handlers:CustomSearchHandler >
</Shell.SearchHandler>

Below is the main shell page where i have added flyout items.
<FlyoutItem x:Name="MainPageTitle"
            Title="{Binding [MainPage], Source={x:Static util:Translator.Instance}}"
            Icon="menu_status.png">
    <ShellContent x:Name="MainShell"
                  Title="{Binding [MainPage], Source={x:Static util:Translator.Instance}}"
                  Icon="menu_status.png"
                  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:PlatformPage}"
                  Route="MainPageRoute" />
</FlyoutItem>

<FlyoutItem Title="{Binding [SecondMenu], Source={x:Static util:Translator.Instance}}"
            Icon="sync.png">
    <ShellContent Route="sync"
                  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:secondPage}"
                  IsVisible="{Binding CanGoOnline, Converter={StaticResource InvertedBoolConverter}}">
    </ShellContent>
</FlyoutItem>

from my main page i am navigating to other pages like below
var navigationParameter = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    { "test", 123 }
};

await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("subPage", navigationParameter);        

}
when i click on the second Page(flyout item) from subpage it navigates to 2nd flyout correctly. When i click on the mainpage flyout item ,during navigation the search handler which is added in the platform page is disappeared

Can you provide some related code about this issue? What do you mean the search handler disappear?

@GuangyuBai-MSFT i have uploaded some code. The Search handler from the flyout page is not displaying

I tested the code by using the SearchHandler, it worked well on my side, I need more research for this issue.

I cannot reproduce the issue. Can you share step by step ways to reproduce this issue?

Please include in the question what .NET version you are using and the platform you are targeting on.
